# How to solve the compiling problems when I use armadillo library'

Tags: c++, armadillo

I'm new in C++ and I tried to use Armadillo to find the eigenvalues of a symmetrical matrix (eig_sym is the function's name). I used 'g++ -std=c++14 main.cpp -o app -O2 -larmadillo -llapack -lbas' and the exit was

error: ‘eig_sym’ was not declared in this scope
  eig_sym( eigval, A );
                     ^
eigval_sym.cpp:44:21: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/armadillo:443:0,
                 from main.cpp:6:
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/fn_eig_sym.hpp:118:1: note:   ‘arma::eig_sym’

,but in the main.cpp file I wrote #include . When is the failure? Library path is not found maybe?

Comment: From the error message, it can't find a declaration for `eig_sym` in your .cpp, and is suggesting `arma::eig_sym`. Add the missing scope and try again.

Comment: Just `#include <armadillo>` should be enough. Does it actually find armadillo headers?

Answer (score 1):

just `#include <armadillo>` is enough to get all functionality from the armadillo library, but do note that everything in armadillo is in the `arma` [namespace](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_namespaces.htm). Therefore, you need to either add `using namespace arma;` in your cpp file or prepend all functions and classes in armadillo with `arma::`. That is, use `arma::eig_sym` instead of just `eig_sym` or add the `using` directive and continue to write just `eig_sym`.

This is the same thing you need to do with the standard library, which is in the namespace `std`. You need to write `std::cout` and not just `cout`, unless you add `using namespace std;`.